# Unpacking tuples/arrays/lists as indices for Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I would love to be able to do

```
>>> A = numpy.array(((1,2),(3,4)))
>>> idx = (0,0)
>>> A[*idx]
```

and get

```
1
```

however this is not valid syntax. Is there a way of doing this without explicitly writing out

```
>>> A[idx[0], idx[1]]
```

?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. In my program I was indexing with a Numpy array rather than a tuple and getting strange results. Converting to a tuple as Alok suggests does the trick.

Comment: It was a tough call. In the end I thought Vicki could do with the points more than you. Still gave you an upvote though :-)

Comment: Also, I guess Vicki's answer illustrates that I can use the example tuple directly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's easier than you think:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> A = numpy.array(((1,2),(3,4)))
>>> idx = (0,0)
>>> A[idx]
1
```

Comment: it is due to the difference between `tuples` and `arrays`

Answer (score 22):

Try

```
A[tuple(idx)]
```

Unless you have a more complex use case that's not as simple as this example, the above should work for all arrays.

Comment: @Mike: yes, but the question title says it might be a list or an array.

Comment: Works for Pytorch too.

Answer (score 6):

*No unpacking is necessary*—when you have a comma between `[` and `]`, you are making a tuple, not passing arguments. `foo[bar, baz]` is equivalent to `foo[(bar, baz)]`. So if you have a tuple `t = bar, baz` you would simply say `foo[t]`.

Answer (score 4):

Indexing an object calls:

```
object.__getitem__(index)
```

When you do A[1, 2], it's the equivalent of:

```
A.__getitem__((1, 2))
```

So when you do:

```
b = (1, 2)

A[1, 2] == A[b]
A[1, 2] == A[(1, 2)]
```

Both statements will evaluate to True.

If you happen to index with a list, it *might* not index the same, as [1, 2] != (1, 2)