# Operator + to add a tuple to another tuple stored inside a multidimensional array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, tuples

I recently found out how to use tuples thanks to great contributions from SO users(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265751/tuple-as-index-of-multidimensional-array)). However I encounter the problem that I can't add a tuple to another tuple stored inside an array of tuples. For instance if I define:

```
arrtup=empty((2,2),dtype=('int,int'))
arrtup[0,1]=(3,4)
```

Then if I try to add another tuple to the existing tupe to come up with a multidimensional index:

```
arrtup[0,1]+(4,4)
```

I obtain this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.void' and 'tuple'
```

Instead of the expected `(3,4,4,4)` tuple, which I can obtain by:

```
(3,4)+(4,4)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing different concepts, I'm afraid.

Your `arrtup` array is **not** an array of tuples, it's a structured `ndarray`, that is, an array of elements that look like tuples but in fact are records (`numpy.void` objects, to be exact). In your case, you defined these records to consist in 2 integers. Internally, NumPy creates your array as a 2x2 array of blocks, each block taking a given space defined by your `dtype`: here, a block consists of 2 consecutive blocks of size `int` (that is, each sub-block takes the space an `int` takes on your machine).

When you retrieve an element with `arrtup[0,1]`, you get the corresponding block. Because this block is structured as two-subblocks, NumPy returns a `numpy.void` (the generic object representing structured blocks), which has the same `dtype` as your array.

Because you set the size of those blocks at the creation of the array, you're no longer able to modify it. That means that you cannot transform your 2-int records into 4-int ones as you want.

However, you can transform you structured array into an array of *objects*:

```
new_arr = arrtup.astype(object)
```

Lo and behold, your elements are no longer `np.void` but tuples, that you can modify as you want:

```
new_arr[0,1] = (3,4) # That's a tuple
new_arr[0,1] += (4,4) # Adding another tuple to the element
```

Your `new_arr` is a different beast from your `arrtup`: it has the same size, true, but it's no longer a structured array, it's an array of objects, as illustrated by

```
>>> new_arr.dtype
dtype("object")
```

In practice, the memory layout is quite different between `arrtup` and `newarr`. `newarr` doesn't have the same constraints as `arrtup`, as the individual elements can have different sizes, but object arrays are not as efficient as structured arrays.

Comment: That is a very nice explanation, thanks! So in practical termns, the ndarray is always filled with `numpy.void` objects, regardless of what the `dtype` says. In that case, the `dtype` is only a useful definition in terms of storing data, since I am able to store a tupe of the kind if defined, but not able to retrieve it. Right? I still dont understand what's the point in not being able to just yield the object out of the array in the shape I defined it with .

Comment: That's cool! Thank you, so instead of the initial `empty` statement I will extend it to `arrtup=empty((2,2),dtype=('int,int')).astype(object)` or a shorter less specific version of `arrtup=empty((2,2),dtype=object)`. Thank you!

Comment: @vint-i-vuit: Yep, using `object` for your `dtype` will let you do what you want. Compare `np.empty((2,2), dtype=(int,int))` and `np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)`

Comment: @Pierre GM: actually `np.empty((2,2), dtype=(int,int))` defines an array in each ndarray position, not a tuple, right? You need the single quotes like: `dtype=('int,int')`. But I agree with your point :)

Comment: @vint-i-vuit I meant `dtype=[('',int),('',int)]`,sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The traceback is pretty clear here.  `arrtup[0,1]` is not a tuple.  It's of type `numpy.void'.

You can convert it to a tuple quite easily however:

```
tuple(arrtup[0,1])
```

which can be concatenated with other tuples:

```
tuple(arrtup[0,1]) + (4,4)
```

Comment: To elaborate - numpy doesn't provide `__add__` for its `void` type/object; and considering the name, it makes sense.

Comment: damnit, but why is it a void!? I fill it with a tuple, dont I?

Comment: @vint-i-vuit -- No -- you fill it with the integers that were stored in your tuple.  when you do `a[...] = ...`, the `__setitem__` method is called on `a`.  In this case, `__setitem__` takes the information from the tuple and stores it as a `numpy.void` type.

Comment: that works, thanks! but I still don't understand why I can't retrieve the tuple stored.