# pytorch modify array with list of indices

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a list of indices and wish to modify an existing array with this list. Currently the only way I can do this is by using a for loop as follows. Just wondering if there is a faster/ efficient way.

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
a = torch.randn(5,3)
idx = torch.Tensor([[1,2], [3,2]], dtype=torch.long)
for i,j in idx:
    a[i,j] = 1
```

I initially assumed that `gather` or `index_select` would go some way in answering this question, but looking at [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) this doesn't seem to be the answer.

In my particular case, a is a 5 dimensional vector and idx is a Nx5 vector. So the output (after subscripting with something like `a[idx]`) I'd expect is a `(N,)` shaped vector.

## Answer

Thanks to @shai below, the answer that I was seeking was:
`a[idx.t().chunk(chunks=2,dim=0)]`. Taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092603/2530674).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
a[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = 1
```

You can find a more general solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52092230/1714410).

Comment: Would this scale even if say a had 5 dimensions. Will wait to see if there is a more general answer before accepting. Sorry for adding the additional requirement late.

Comment: @sachinruk please see the added link.