# Index multidimensional torch tensor with array of variable length

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, pytorch, tensor

I have a list of indices and a tensor with shape:

```
shape = [batch_size, d_0, d_1, ..., d_k]
idx = [i_0, i_1, ..., i_k]
```

Is there a way to efficiently index the tensor on each dim `d_0, ..., d_k` with the indices `i_0, ..., i_k`? (`k` is available only at run time)

The result should be:

```
tensor[:, i_0, i_1, ..., i_k] #tensor.shape = [batch_size]
```

At the moment I'm creating a tuple of slices, one for each dimension:

```
idx = (slice(tensor.shape[0]),) + tuple(slice(i, i+1) for i in idx)
tensor[idx]
```

but I would prefer something like:

```
tensor[:, *idx]
```

---

**Example:**

```
a = torch.randint(0,10,[3,3,3,3])
indexes = torch.LongTensor([1,1,1])
```

I would like to index only the last len(indexes) dimensions like:

```
a[:, indexes[0], indexes[1], indexes[2]]
```

but in the general case where I don't know how long `indexes` is.

---

**Note:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092886/6660601) does not help since it indexes *all* the dimensions, and does not work for a proper subset!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you [can't provide](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html)<sup>1</sup> a mix of slices and iterators to an indexing (e.g. `a[:,*idx]`). However, you can achieve almost the same thing by wrapping it in brackets to cast to an iterator:

```py
a[(slice(None), *idx)]
```

---

1. > In Python, `x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)]` is equivalent to `x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]`; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html