# NumPy: pass subset of multi-dimensional indices to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, multi-index

Suppose I have an array, and a (sub)set of indices:

```py
arr = np.array([[[0,1,2],
                 [3,4,5],
                 [6,7,8]],
                
                [[9, 10,11],
                 [12,13,14],
                 [15,16,17]]])
idx = [1,2]
```

And I wish to get, for each element of dim=0 of the array, the respective `idx` slice, i.e.:

```py
>>> arr[:, idx[0], idx[1]]
array([ 5, 14])
```

Is there a way to do such slicing without hard-coding each index? Something like:

```py
ar[:, *idx]
```

---

Note, [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903664/9067615) is my current workaround:

```py
idx = [slice(a.shape[0]), *idx]
a[idx]
```

but I was wondering if NumPy (or PyTorch, or a related library) supported a more 'elegant'/natural multi-dimensional indexing syntax for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your workaround is pretty much as close as you can get.

You can try this to make it slightly more concise:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0,1,2],
                 [3,4,5],
                 [6,7,8]],

                [[9, 10,11],
                 [12,13,14],
                 [15,16,17]]])
idx = [1,2]

print(
    arr[(slice(None), *idx)]
)
```

This works because `:` is the same as `slice(None)`