# Pytorch setting elements to zero with "tensor index"

Tags: indexing, pytorch, mask, tensor, max-pooling

I've used Pytorch for a few months. But I recently want to create a customized pooling layer which is similar to the "Max-Pooling Dropout" layer and I think Pytorch provided us a bunch of tools to build such a layer I need. Here is my approach:

1. use MaxPool2d with indices returned
2. set tensor[indices] to zero
3. I want it behaves like torch.take (without flatten) if possible.

here is how to get the "index tensor". (I think it is called "index tensor". correct me if I was wrong)

```
input1 = torch.randn(1, 1, 6, 6)
m = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2, return_indices=True)
val, indx = m(input1)
```

indx is the "index tensor" which can be used easily as

```
torch.take(input1, indx)
```

No flatten needed, no argument needed to set dimension. I think it make sense since indx is generated from input1.

Question: how do I set the values input1 pointed by indx to 0 in the "torch.take" style? I saw some answers like [Indexing a multi-dimensional tensor with a tensor in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092230/indexing-a-multi-dimensional-tensor-with-a-tensor-in-pytorch). But I don't think FB returning such "index tensor" thing which cannot be applied directly. (Maybe I was wrong.)

Is there something like

```
torch.set_value(input1, indx, 0) ?
```

Comment: Generating a mask tensor and multiplying it can be the trick, but cannot avoid flattening since values of index tensor are based on flattened one. `mask=torch.ones_like(input1); mask.view(-1)[indx.view(-1)] = 0; input1 * mask`

Comment: Thanks Hayoung. This is a working solution. So far, I don't see how powerful the "tensor index" is. Maybe it is just used in some special scenarios. torch.take is just one of such scenario...