# Indexing a multi-dimensional array partially

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(50,3,3,3,16)
ids = (0,0,2,10)
b = arr[:, ids]  # don't work
b = arr[:, *ids]  # don't work
b = arr[:][ids]  # don't work
b = arr[:, tuple(ids)]  # don't work
b = arr[: + ids]  # don't work, obviously..
# b = arr[:,0,0,2,10].shape  # works (desired outcome)
```

I know there have been several questions about this, like [Tuple as index of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12265751) or [Unpacking tuples/arrays/lists as indices for Numpy Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2444923) but none of them work for my case. Basically I want to index everything in the first axis, of specified "columns" in the rest of the axes (see the last line of my code).
The desired output shape should be `(50,)` in this case.

But I want to index with a tuple/list of ids because I need to iterate through them, for example:

```
all_ids = ((0,0,0,2), (0,0,0,6), (1,1,0,2), (1,1,0,6),
           (2,2,0,2), (2,2,0,6), (2,2,2,2), (2,2,2,6))
c = 0
for id in all_ids:
    c += arr[:, id].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `slice(None)` to first dimension in `ids` and then subset:

```
arr[(slice(None),) + ids].shape
# (50,)
```

where:

```
(slice(None),) + ids
# (slice(None, None, None), 0, 0, 2, 10)
```

Notice `slice(None, None, None)` is equivalent to `:`, i.e. slice all. You can read [docs on using `slice` object for indexing here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#index-2).