# Transform tuple into indices?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seems trivial on first look, yet surprisingly I haven't managed to find any answer online - consider the following list:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

In order to get 5, I can go `my_list[1][1]`, by 5's position of course.

Suppose I have the following tuple:

```
t = (1, 1)
```

Can I use this tuple in order to get 5 in a more appealing way then `my_list[t[0]][t[1]]` ?

**Edit**: please also take *assignment* into account, i.e more appealing then

```
my_list[t[0]][t[1]] = value
```

and final elements which are not necessarily numeric, e.g `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`

Answer (score 3):

use `reduce`:

```
result = reduce(lambda acc, i: acc[i], t, my_list)
```

demo:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> t = (1, 1)
>>> reduce(lambda acc, i: acc[i], t, my_list)
5
```

#### UPDATE

if an update is required:

```
reduce(lambda acc, i: acc[i], t[:-1], my_list)[t[-1]]
```

returns a "left value"(if i may say so). but it becomes ugly then, since the consistency of the expression is broken. and really, it can't wrapped as a function either.

i would suggest to write a simple wrapper like this:

```
class mdlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            assert len(item) >= 1
            return self[item[0]][item[1:]] if len(item) > 1 else self[item[0]]
        else:
            return super(mdlist, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            assert len(item) >= 1
            if len(item) > 1:
                self[item[0]][item[1:]] = value
            else:
                self[item[0]] = value
        else:
            super(mdlist, self).__setitem__(item, value)
```

it doesn't take more than you think and ease your life a lot.

Comment: Nice! But wouldn't it make sense to have something like this built-in..? Weird. If nobody will come up with something else, I'm taking it :)

Comment: @Kludge as far as i know, there is no such builtin. you either use for-loop, or this. but using for-loop is quite stupid for such a piece of short code.

Comment: What if I need to assign a new value to the [t] position?

Comment: Note that `reduce` was moved in Python 3.x into the `functools` module.

Answer (score 2):

I think NumPy package just fit what you need. First turn the list into a NumPy array, then you can select a item by its position tuple.

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
my_array = np.array(my_list)
t = (1, 1)
print my_array[t]
```

Comment: NumPy did index item by tuple or NumPy array. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

Comment: I already tried before I post. There is a similay answer, if you still don't believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444923/unpacking-tuples-arrays-lists-as-indices-for-numpy-arrays

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. What was wrong with my interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

You could use tuple unpacking to get your tuple values ( and ultimately you r list indices into variables )

```
>>> one , two = t
>>> mylist[one][two]
5
```

Comment: It's just a *bit* nicer. I was hoping for something like my_list[magic(t)].

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to do that:

```
def nested_index(l, t):
    e = l
    for i in t:
        e = e[i]
    return e
```

Then you can call the function as:

```
nested_index(my_list, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create `operator.itemgetter` objects and apply them successively.

Example for two levels of nesting:

```
import operator
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
t = (1,2)
i1, i2 = map(operator.itemgetter, t)

>>> i2(i1(a))
6
```

Example for n levels of nesting (you have to ensure the target structure can accommodate the length of the tuple, maybe wrap it in a try/except):

```
a = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],['a','b','c']]]
t = (0,1,0) # should produce 4
z = a[:]
for op_ig in map(operator.itemgetter, t):
    z = op_ig(z)

>>> z
4
```

To go a bit further using a couple of functions from [`functionally`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functionally/1.0.1)

```
from functionally import compose, thrush
a = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],['a','b','c']]]
t = (1,1,0) # should produce a
foo = compose(*map(operator.itemgetter, reversed(t)))

>>> foo(a)
'a'
>>> thrush(a, *(operator.itemgetter(i) for i in t))
'a'
```