# Use array to define indices for multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional Numpy array; let's say it's

```
 myArray = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
                   [ 3,  4,  5],
                   [ 6,  7,  8]],

                  [[ 9, 10, 11],
                   [12, 13, 14],
                   [15, 16, 17]],

                  [[18, 19, 20],
                   [21, 22, 23],
                   [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I know that running `myArray[1,1,1]`, for instance, will return 13. However, I want to define `indx = [1,1,1]` then call something to the effect of`myArray[indx]`. 
However, this does some other multidimensional indexing stuff.

I have also tried `myArray[*indx]` but that understandably throws a syntax error.

Currently my *very* ugly workaround is to define

```
def array_as_indices(array, matrix):
    st = ''
    for i in array:
        st += '%s,' % i
    st = st[:-1]

    return matrix[eval(st)]
```

which works but is quite inelegant and presumably slow.

Is there a more pythonic way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: use `myArray[tuple(indx)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices of a numpy array are addressed by tuples, not lists. Use `indx = (1, 1, 1)`.

As an extension, if you want to call the indices (1, 1, 1) and (2, 2, 2), you can use

```
>>> indx = ([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2])
>>> x[indx]
array([13, 26])
```

---

The rationale behind the behavior with lists is that numpy treats lists sequentially, so

```
>>> indx = [1, 1, 1]
>>> x[indx]
array([[[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],
       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],
       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

It returns a list of three elements, each equal to x[1].

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [Unpacking tuples/arrays/lists as indices for Numpy Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444923/unpacking-tuples-arrays-lists-as-indices-for-numpy-arrays), but you can just create a tuple

```py
import numpy as np


def main():
    my_array = np.array(
        [
            [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
            [[9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]],
            [[18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]],
        ]
    )
    print(f"my_array[1,1,1]: {my_array[1,1,1]}")
    indx = (1, 1, 1)
    print(f"my_array[indx]: {my_array[indx]}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

will give

```
my_array[1,1,1]: 13
my_array[indx]: 13
```