# How do I read in a list of indices and returning the value of a multidimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an N dimensional square (cubic etc.) numpy array `n`, and a list of indices `l` I would like a function to return `n[l[0]][l[1]]...[l[N-1]]`

For example:

if

```
n = [[0,1,2],
     [3,4,5],
     [6,7,8]]
```

and

```
l = [1,1]
```

an operation

```
f(n,l) = 4
```

or if

```
n = [[[0,1],
      [2,3]],
     [[4,5],
      [6,7]]]
```

and

```
l = [1,0,1]
```

an operation

```
f(n,l) = 5
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to make a code where I can change the dimensionality of a simulation without having to recode something new for different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you only need numpy to do this for you. With your examples for `n` you can do

```
n =np.array( [[0,1,2],
     [3,4,5],
     [6,7,8]])

l = (1,1)
n[l]
```

Note that `l` needs to be a tuple (round parentheses). You can convert your list as

```
l = [1,1]
n[tuple(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your array to a tuple:

```py
import numpy as np


def f(n, i):
    return n[tuple(i)]


print(
    f(
        np.arange(0, 9).reshape((3, 3)),
        np.array([1, 1])
    )
)
print(
    f(
        np.arange(0, 8).reshape((2, 2, 2)),
        np.array([1, 0, 1])
    )
)
```

Output:

```
4
5
```

See: [Unpacking tuples/arrays/lists as indices for Numpy Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2444923/15497888)