# Get a list of values from a 3D numpy array using a list of 3-component indices (4D array)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I've looked through many different answers for indexing 2D and 3D arrays and I can't quite find a simple solution to my problem. I have a 3D array and have a list of 3-component indices (ix, iy, iz). I would like a list of values from the array, where each value is chosen using the one of the 3-component indices.

I've been able to solve the problem by flattening the array with `reshape()` and `np.apply_along` axis, but this seems inelegant, especially since I need to define a function to convert the 3-component indices to 1-component indices.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(125).reshape(5,5,5)
indices = np.array(((0, 0, 0), (4, 4, 4), (0, 0, 4)), dtype=int)

# For-loop implementation
values = []
for i in indices:
    values.append(data[i[0], i[1], i[2]])
print(values)


# My inelegant numpy implementation
def three_to_one(index3d,dim):
    return index3d[0]*dim[1]*dim[2] + index3d[1]*dim[2] + index3d[2]

indices_1d = np.apply_along_axis(three_to_one, 1, indices, data.shape)
data_flat = data.reshape(-1)
values = data_flat[indices_1d]
print(values)
```

Comment: As a general rule I regard `apply_along` to be in-elegant.  Under the covers it's just an iterator..  I doubt if it's any faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by transposing indices and [using tuple()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444923/unpacking-tuples-arrays-lists-as-indices-for-numpy-arrays) to interpret each column of indices as an index into data.

```
>>> data[tuple(indices.T)]
array([  0, 124,   4])
```

Comment: I've been going through all the "advanced" array indexing functions in numpy and the solution wasn't there at all!

Comment: The underlying feature is that for all indexing, `x[i,j]`, `x[(i,j)]`, `x[tuple(i,j)]` are the same. Comma, in most contexts, makes a tuple.

Comment: From the lead paragraph of the basic indexing page: `Note that in Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.`  Use of tuples in indexing applies to scalars, slices (basic indexing), as well as arrays (advanced indexing).  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html @WaterMolecule

Answer (score 2):

[Starting with Python-3.11](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#implications), this works:

```py
data[*indices.T]
```

In older python versions, this is equivalent:

```py
data[tuple(indices.T)]
```

The trick is that you can give one sequence per dimension, comma-separated or as a tuple (not a list!). You see this in use with [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```py
data = np.random.random((4, 5, 6))
above = data[np.nonzero(a > 0.75)]
```

Comment: This is a SyntaxError for me - which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @NickODell Interesting. Python-3.11.5 with Numpy-1.25.2. What's it on your side?

Comment: @NickODell I also get a syntax error in 3.6. I don't have any versions in-between and in a quick scan of the release notes I couldn't find the relevant change. Would be interesting to know which version is required

Comment: This works for me with Python-3.11.5 with Numpy-1.25.2

Comment: @WaterMolecule Thanks. It doesn't work in Python 3.10.12, so that just gave me one version to check. The behavior is described in the [Implications section of PEP 646 – Variadic Generics](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#implications). So this is a Python 3.11 feature.

Comment: @NickODell thanks for clarifying. I incorporated it into the answer

Comment: `*x` unpacks the elements of `x` (first dimension is `x` is an array) into a tuple.   It's often used in the form `i,j = *x`, and also in function calls, `foo(*x)`.  Allowing it in indexing is a recent addition to python.