# Numpy advanced indexing with index arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy, I got stuck with an advanced case of indexing problem. Suppose that I have an array `A` with the shape`(D0,D1,...,D(N-1),A,B)`. So, the first N dimensions are where I want to query for indices. The last two dimensions (A,B) are holding the actual data. I have a list of tuples of N dimensions, of length `K`, that act as indices into the first N dimensions, say `indices`. I did expect that `A[indices]` would return me another array of the shape `(K,A,B)`. However this does not seems to be the case. An example:

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 4, 4, 3, 3))
indices = [(0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
indices = np.stack(indices, axis=0)
selected_arr = arr[indices]
print(selected_arr.shape)
```

The result is `(5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3)` instead of `(5, 3, 3)`. I thought that every row of the indices array would index the first three dimensions of arr, however this doesnt seem to be true.

Is there a way to achieve the indexing behavior I am thinking of in numpy?

Comment: Your `indices` is a (5,3) array, right?  For indexing you supply a tuple, or a separate array for each dimension.  `arr[ indices[:,0], indices[:,1], indices[:,2] ]`

Comment: With `arr[indices]` you are using that (5,3) array to select items along the first, size 4, dimension, hence the (5,3, ...) result.  For numpy indexing, indexing with a tuple is important.

Comment: That's basically the same we just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311268/get-a-list-of-values-from-a-3d-numpy-array-using-a-list-of-3-component-indices/77311516#77311516 Use `arr[tuple(zip(*indices))]`. No need for `stack` first

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I have just remembered how numpy distinguishes indexing with an ndarray and a conventional tuple, now it works!